# javax.ws.rs.core.Response convert to string in java1.6

Tags: rest, jax-rs, java-6

I want to convert Response to string

```
Response response  = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().sslContext(sslContext).build().target(url)
                        .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();

// I have tried as below.. It didn't work
String result = (String)response.getEntity();
```

Error is `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector$1 cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

Please not i am using Java 1.6 version and i cannot find methods like readEntity(String.class) and getEntity(String.class) from Response class.

Alternate way works as below by giving String.class in get.
But i need Response object First to check the status code then i want to convert it to String.

```
String response =     ClientBuilder.newBuilder().sslContext(sslContext).build().target(url)
                                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class);
```

Please assist in solving this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we don't use Jersey client jar, then we don't get readEntity(class) and getEntity(class). These methods are not part of javax.ws.rs.core.Response they are part of Jersey clientjar. So if we are using javax.ws.rs.core.Response, then we have to manually convert as below

```
    javax.ws.rs.core.Response response; 
    String result = readInputStreamAsString((InputStream) response.getEntity());

public static String readInputStreamAsString(InputStream in) {
        try {
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(in);
            ByteArrayOutputStream buf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int result = bis.read();
            while (result != -1) {
                byte b = (byte) result;
                buf.write(b);
                result = bis.read();
            }
            return buf.toString();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`readEntity()`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.html) method is the way to go:

```java
Response response = ...
String value = response.readEntity(String.class);
```

---

I don't understand why you are saying that such method is not available for you: the [`ClientBuilder`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.html) class (just like the [`readEntity()`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.html) method) was also introduced in JAX-RS 2.0 (Java EE 7) as part of the [Client API](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/client/package-summary.html).

Don't you have any JAX-RS 1.x dependencies in the classpath?

Comment: You can see in Java 1.6 docs that readEntity(String.class) and getEntity(String.class) is missing. only available method is getEntity() https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html

Comment: @Rohit That's Java EE 6 and not Java SE 6. As I mentioned in my answer, you won't find `ClientBuillder` is that documentation.  It makes me think your classpath is messy.